# Tool or script to pull all NuGet licenses used in the solution

Tags: windows, package-manager, parser

Is there a tool or script that can pull libraries and its license(s) in a single file?

**Input:** root source folder

```
C:\src\project_bananna
```

**Output:** text file, perhaps in csv format

```
+----------------------------+----------+-------------+
|       NuGet package        | Version  |  Licenses   |
+----------------------------+----------+-------------+
| JQuery                     | 1.4      | MIT License |
| Json.NET                   | 7        | MIT License |
| ...                        | ...      | ...         |
+----------------------------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as far as I could get using the [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console).

> The Package Manager Console is a PowerShell console within Visual
>   Studio used to interact with NuGet and automate Visual Studio.

The only problem is that, for what I've seen, there's no (easy) way to get the license type as you'd like, just the **license URL**. In any case, this gives you an idea to get started with something and might be sufficient for your purpose.

I've used the [Get-Package cmdlet](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference): open the Package Manager Console and type the following, replacing OUTPUT_CSV with the path and name of the output CSV file you want to create:

```
Get-Package | Select-Object Id,Version,LicenseUrl | Export-Csv OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

I've tested it with a random project of mine, and this is the content of the output CSV file:

```
"Id","Version","LicenseUrl"
"Google.Apis","1.9.1","http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
"Google.Apis.Auth","1.9.0","http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
"Google.Apis.Core","1.9.1","http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
"Google.Apis.YouTube.v3","1.9.0.1360","http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
"log4net","2.0.3","http://logging.apache.org/log4net/license.html"
"Microsoft.Bcl","1.1.9","http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=329770"
"Microsoft.Bcl.Async","1.0.168","http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=329770"
"Microsoft.Bcl.Build","1.0.14","http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=329770"
"Microsoft.Net.Http","2.2.28","http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=329770"
"Newtonsoft.Json","6.0.8","https://raw.github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/master/LICENSE.md"
"Zlib.Portable","1.10.0","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib_License"
```